# Jupyter Notebook Markdown Latex on Github

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

I would like to have a simple answer, if any, on a problem that other people had and asked probably but about which so far I didn't find exhaustive answers. The problem is the following :

Uploading on Github, a Jupyter notebook file.ipynb containing markdown cells like:

> \begin{equation}
>   \sum_i\hat{f}_i
>   \end{equation}

The result on Github is simply horrible: random space or position, and ugly displaying of formula (to give an example the '\hat').

Is there something I'm missing ?

Thanks for anyone who will help me.

Comment: I also have this issue. When try use bra ket notation it either makes the | too small or too big.